# reactjs/ occupy 100% height without scrollbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Well I wanted to leave a page with 100% screen height
without scroll bar:

```
const SignIn = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}  direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" >
        <Grid  item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12} >      
        <img src={require("../nodejs-icon.svg")} alt="bug" height={100} />
        </Grid> 
        </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and my css:

```
const loginStyle = (muiBaseTheme => ({
    root:{
        background: "#000",
        minHeight: '100vh',
    }
}));
```

But i'm getting a horizontal and vertical scroll bar like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvtYI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```cs
const loginStyle = (muiBaseTheme => ({
    root:{
        background: "#000",
        minHeight: '100vh',
        overflow: 'hidden',

    }
}));
```

to hide the scroll bars.

Comment: Hello could you help me as I put the children of this div in the center?

Comment: This should align what you have inside the Grid, `<Grid container spacing={2}  direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" alignContent="center">`

You can also delete the div and instead use the grid directly.

Comment: I did it on div,
but inside a grid item I can't get a typografh on flex start page

Comment: Open a new post question with a minimal code and a reproducible example of the problem you are facing, I'll try to help you.